# QGIS Reset Attribute Table Views

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a geodatabase file with attributes columns that exist in the correct order, however, when I view the attribute table in QGIS it re-sorts that order (possibly due to a previous copy-paste of styles).

Is there any way to reset the attribute table settings for a layer, and let QGIS start afresh displaying the columns in their native order?

Comment: Try re-loading the layer without the copied style. Then copy *only* the style categories that you need. Don't copy the "Fields" and "Forms" categories of the style.

Comment: While that works (thanks!) it's super-tedious... Would rather work backwards and reset the few style(s) I don't need, rather than set up everything I do need from scratch...

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using? In QGIS 3 you can paste separate aspects of layer style, such as "symbology" or "diagrams." Pasting several times hardly seems "super-tedious" to me.

Comment: "New Layer -> Copy Style Part A -> Paste Style Part A -> Copy Style Part B -> Paste Style Part B -> Copy Style Part C -> Paste Style Part C -> etc..." is a lot more tedious than "New Layer -> Copy All Styles -> Paste All Styles -> RESET Style part D"

Comment: duplicate the layer. copy all styles to the original. copy the relevant style part from the duplicate onto the original. that's slightly fewer steps.